# jQuery index of element with some class

Tags: jquery, indexing

I have this code to get index of element in parents container:

```
var pi = parentContainer.find('.foo[data-media-id='+value+']'),
    index = parentContainer.children('.foo').index(pi);
```

Do I have a step too many or is this a right way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `.index()`? https://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: @user7290573 Erm... It's right there in the example -> `.index(pi);`

Comment: Oh, oops - misread your question, sorry. Been a long day…